# deploying djangoappengine on google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

I copied the 4 folders it said to:

django-nonrel/django => /django

djangotoolbox/djangotoolbox => /djangotoolbox

django-dbindexer/dbindexer => /dbindexer

djangoappengine => /djangoappengine

And uploaded the test app (just the contents inside django-testapp)

But I get a massive error message when I run it.

Comment: Do you think you could tell us what the "massive error message" is?

Comment: +1 "massive error message" doesn't tell us much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying "massive error message" is not specific enough to get good debugging help. Assuming you're describing a traceback, post it! (The error screen has a "Switch to copy-and-paste view" that's handy for this.)